# MySQL Composite Index Question - Performance issue

Tags: mysql, sql, date, query-optimization, where-clause

I have done some research on the index before posting the question here. So far I believe I have done this correctly, but for some reason, the performance of a query that returns around 2400 records has not been good.

Here is the table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `tblCheck` (
    `id` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `token` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `domainId` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `time` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `responseCode` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `totalTime` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `namelookupTime` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `connectTime` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pretransferTime` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `startTransferTime` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `redirectTime` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `appconnectTime` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `responseText` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `agentId` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `isHealthy` CHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `ftp_connect_time` DECIMAL(10,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ftp_login_time` DECIMAL(10,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ftp_change_mode_time` DECIMAL(10,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ftp_list_time` DECIMAL(10,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `syntheticToken` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `domainId` (`domainId`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `deleteTime` (`time`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `SearchIndex` (`domainId`, `time`, `agentId`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
;
```

The Query

```
SELECT *
FROM `tblCheck`
WHERE (`time` BETWEEN '2020-05-04 22:15:04' AND '2020-05-05 22:15:04')
  AND `domainId` = '03d4c1ce-8b13-11ea-abf5-124e96b5f417'
  AND `agentId` != '145a-f6bb-11e8-983f-1231322cbdb6'
ORDER BY `time` DESC
;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 2,418  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.109 sec. (+ 10.360 sec. network) */
```

It returned 2418 rows but took almost 10s.

Running it with EXPLAIN

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM `tblCheck`
WHERE (`time` BETWEEN '2020-05-04 22:15:04' AND '2020-05-05 22:15:04')
  AND `domainId` = '03d4c1ce-8b13-11ea-abf5-124e96b5f417'
  AND `agentId` != '145a-f6bb-11e8-983f-1231322cbdb6'
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

Returns this

[image]

This looks like it is using the index "SearchIndex". However, I can't figure out why it would take to process 10s for 2k rows

Comment: `DECIMAL` for times?

Comment: Why no `PRIMARY KEY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tblCheck`
WHERE 
    `time` BETWEEN '2020-05-04 22:15:04' AND '2020-05-05 22:15:04'
    AND `domainId` = '03d4c1ce-8b13-11ea-abf5-124e96b5f417' 
    AND `agentId` != '145a-f6bb-11e8-983f-1231322cbdb6'
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

The right index would be: `(domainId, agentId, time)`, or `(domainId, time, agentId)`. You have an the second index in place, and the query plan shows that MySQL happily uses it.

Looking at the explain summary, you can see:

> Duration for 1 query: 0.109 sec. (+ 10.360 sec. network)

The query runs fast in the database. The bottleneck is the network, that is the time taken to return the 2000+ rows from the database to the client. Not much can be done from database perspective. Speed up your network, or switch to a local database if you can.

As a side note: `select *` is a not good for performance; you should try and reduce the number of columns that the query returns (this might also reduce the amount that needs to transmitted over the network).

Comment: I think I agree with you. The column 'responseText' contains some large amounts of string data. When I did a SELECT all column except 'responseText' it worked great and returned the data under a second. It should be the network. Thanks !

Comment: It uses only `domainId` from that index.  (Notice key_len = 53 = 50+2+1).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the primary key.
You only have a UNIQUE INDEX.

Comment: That won't explain the sluggishness.  Note, also, that the unique index is NULLable, hence it cannot be promoted to PK.

Answer (score 0):

If you con't nee that bulky `responseText` column in the results, don't include it.  This *may* dramatically speed up the query.

(This is because large columns are stored "off-record", thereby taking an extra disk read if the table is huge.)